# Overriding uiGridHeaderCell

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I want to override ui-grid's **uiGridHeaderCell**.  I can do it by adding the following script tag, with html in the body, to the **head** section of index.html, like this...

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ui-grid/uiGridHeaderCell">
      <div
        role="columnheader"
        ng-class="{ 'sortable': sortable }"
        ui-grid-one-bind-aria-labelledby-grid="col.uid + '-header-text ' + col.uid + '-sortdir-text'"
        aria-sort="{{col.sort.direction == asc ? 'ascending' : ( col.sort.direction == desc ? 'descending' : (!col.sort.direction ? 'none' : 'other'))}}">
        <div
          role="button"
          tabindex="-1"
          class="ui-grid-cell-contents ui-grid-header-cell-primary-focus"
          col-index="renderIndex"
          title="TOOLTIP">
          <span
            class="ui-grid-header-cell-label"
            ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="col.uid + '-header-text'">
            {{ col.displayName CUSTOM_FILTERS }}
          </span>
      
          <span
            ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="col.uid + '-sortdir-text'"
            ui-grid-visible="col.sort.direction"
            aria-label="{{getSortDirectionAriaLabel()}}">
            <i ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-icon-up-dir': col.sort.direction == asc, 'ui-grid-icon-down-dir': col.sort.direction == desc, 'ui-grid-icon-blank': !col.sort.direction }" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      
        <div
          role="button"
          tabindex="-1"
          ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="col.uid + '-menu-button'"
          class="ui-grid-column-menu-button"
          ng-if="grid.options.enableColumnMenus && !col.isRowHeader  && col.colDef.enableColumnMenu !== false"
          ng-click="toggleMenu($event)"
          ng-class="{'ui-grid-column-menu-button-last-col': isLastCol}"
          ui-grid-one-bind-aria-label="i18n.headerCell.aria.columnMenuButtonLabel"
          aria-haspopup="true">
          <i class="ui-grid-icon-angle-down" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>
        </div>
      
        <div ui-grid-filter></div>
      </div>
</script>
```

You can see that I've set the tabindex="-1" so the cellHeader is not part of the tabbing sequence.  This does successfully override the default uiGridHeaderCell.  However, I think this isn't a very clean approach.  I'd rather have that html in it's own file, and reference it from the  tag.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting the `columnDef`s in `scope.gridOptions` for the column(s) on which you want to override the header cell, add a property `headerCellTemplate` and point it to the file name of the html file.

So the column definition will include something like:

```
{
    field: '...', 
    name: '...',
    headerCellTemplate: 'someDirectory/someDirectory/your-custom-html-file.html'
}
```

Edit:

Often when changing templates you need to explictly tell ui-grid to refresh

Normally you can do this with `$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( $scope.gridApi.grid, uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL)` I downloaded your plunk and added that code inside the http.get callback right after `$scope.gridOptions.data = data;` and it works.

On plunker, however, it seems to need to add the data setting to the next digest cyle (I think there is a timing issue in relation to when the templates and data are retrieved by your controller and when ui-grids initial digest cycles are complete). So put the http.get inside a $timeout function, i.e. replace lines 37-39 of your plunk with

```
$timeout(function () {$http.get('./data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
})}, 0);
```

Also, I think you need to reference the template file with a relative path `./uiGridHeaderCell.html` instead of just `uiGridHeaderCell.html`

Working plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/KitYBfKuRTQppuSRUCh7

Comment: Actually, I this isn't working for me now.  It seemed to initially, and now it's not working at all.

Here is a plunker to show what's going on...
http://plnkr.co/rDBRr5xs9rALjTVl5LgC

Comment: It looks like your solution works if you include the entire template as the value, with all the single quote escaped, like this...


**headerCellTemplate: '<div role="columnheader" ng-class="{ \'sortable\': sortable }"  . . .'**

Comment: Updated my answer so that you don't need to include the entire template.